# can pass backbone collection to view error string is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

i am new to backbone trying to send a collection directly to a view template but i fail. Type Error saying that string is not a function. I know that i return correctly my collection maybe i am taking the wrong way to pass my collection into view. Anyway help will be appreciate.

here my view code

```
var EncoursView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: "#contentEncours", //Container div
   template: "tpl/EncoursView.html",
   initialize: function () {
                  console.log('Encours View Initialized');
                  this.collection.fetch();
                  console.log(this.collection);
               },
   render: function () {
                  $(this.el).empty();
                   var that = this;
                  //Fetching the template contents
                  $.get(this.template({lists:this.collection}), function (template) {
                    that.$el.html(template); //adding the template content.
                  }, 'html');

                  return that;
           }
});
```

this is my view trying to iterate my collection

```
<script>
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    escape: /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g
};
    {{ _.each(items, function(item) { }}
        <ul>
            <li>Isin: {{= item.isinCode }}</li>
        </ul>
    {{ }); }}
</script>
```

inside my route i call this function i pass collection to my view and call render

```
remencour: function(){
   var collectionSupport = new SupportCollection();
   this.encoursView = new EncoursView({collection:collectionSupport});
   this.encoursView.render();
}
```

Comment: 1)where is render called? 2) when passing data to template pass it as JSON loke coll.toJSON()

Comment: i add on my post the render call its call inside my route i use a rest service to get my data its already into Json format i don't think i need to call .toJSON()

Comment: collection.fetch is asynch , you can't call render like that

Comment: how i am suppose to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this:

```
$.get(this.template({lists:this.collection}), function (template) {
    that.$el.html(template); //adding the template content.
}, 'html');
```

is meant to retrieve the template source (`tpl/EncoursView.html`) from the server, fill it in, and then insert it into the view's `el`.

There are a couple problems here.

1. `this.template` is the `'tpl/EncoursView.html'` string when you try to call it like a function.
2. [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) expects a URL as its first parameter.
3. Inside the `$.get` callback, `template` should be the template source (once you get that far of course).
4. Your template:

   ```
   {{ _.each(items, function(item) { }}
       <ul>
           <li>Isin: {{= item.isinCode }}</li>
       </ul>
   {{ }); }}
   ```

   doesn't really match the data you're trying to feed it.

You have all the right pieces they're just not in the right places.

**1** and **2** are easy, just give `$.get` the template URL as its first argument. **3** is also fairly easy to deal with: compile the template inside the callback. **4** isn't that difficult either, feed the template serialized data and make sure the name you pass to the template function matches what the template uses:

```
$.get(this.template, function(template) {
    var tmpl = _.template(template);
    var html = tmpl({ items: that.collection.toJSON() });
    // ---------------^^^^^------------------^^^^^^^^
}, 'html');
```

and the template would look the same as it does now.

The [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) call gives you an array of objects, this helps you avoid accidentally changing anything inside a template. This is standard practice with Backbone.